# How can I zoom in finer steps in leaflet?

Tags: r, leaflet, zooming

I plotted a map with leaflet in r. Now I'd like to create a static map. I can zoom into the map an with each step of zooming the mapscale shrinks by 2km.

How can I adjust the zoom levels so the mapscale shrinks by 1km per "zoom"?

Comment: Assuming you're using a raster map tile source, you can't - you're limited to the tile sizes that your tile source has available. If you happen to be using vector tiles, there are some tricks you can do with a custom CRS  - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13154295/adding-an-extra-zoom-levels-in-leaflet-maps for a partial solution.

Comment: Leaflet does have fractional zoom levels (e.g. `map.setZoom(4.75)`) since version 1.0.0. I'm not sure how that plays together with R, though.

Answer (score 8):

[`zoomSnap` and `zoomDelta` control zoom increments](https://leafletjs.com/examples/zoom-levels/):

```
leaflet(data = NULL,
        options = leafletOptions(zoomControl = TRUE,
                                 zoomSnap = 0.25,
                                 zoomDelta = 1)) |>
  addTiles() |> 
  addMarkers(lng = 30.52418, lat = 50.44999,
             label = "#StandWithUkraine") |> 
  addScaleBar(position = "bottomright",
              options = scaleBarOptions(imperial = FALSE)) |>
  fitBounds(lng1 = 30.2989, lat1 = 50.5318,
            lng2 = 30.8249, lat2 = 50.3595)
```